# What Ordinary Differential Equations we still don't have a method to solve despite being proven to have a solution?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

It seems that we cannot solve all differential equations that bump up into nature, and here I mean finding a general or analytical solution, not just numerical approximation (P.S: I'm only referring to the cases where a solution was proven to exist, I'm aware that some diff equation have no solution, so that's not the case of my discussion here).

**1. Give me a list of ODE that we still don't know how to solve and a method is waiting to be invented/discovered, or maybe we need new mathematics to emerge in order to solve these ODEs.**

These are the type of Ordinary Differential Equations and their corresponding methods of solution:

- Separable equations (solution by integration)
- Linear equations (integrating factor method)
- Exact equations (differential of a function of two variables)
- Other (Solution by substitution)

More methods: 
SERIES SOLUTIONS OF LINEAR EQUATIONS and 
THE LAPLACE TRANSFORM

It seems that all these types of ODE have its own methods to solve them, so the scenario that I could imagine is that some nonlinear equations still cannot be solved by any method.

**2. Can you extend the list above by citing more methods used in solving ODEs?**

**3. Are mathematicians trying to find a general method to solve nonlinear ODEs?**

Answer (score 2):

There are many more methods for finding closed-form solutions to differential equations.
Symmetry-based methods are quite powerful, especially when implemented in computer algebra systems, and are still an active area of research.  For example, you might look at
Bluman and Kumei, "[Symmetries and Differential Equations](https://books.google.ca/books?id=ZhbrBwAAQBAJ)".